# Why ArrayList Remove functionality in O(n) not O(n*n)

Tags: algorithm

Please let me know whether the time complexity of the function `Remove`below is O(n) or O(n*n)?

It removes the first item in the collection whose value matches the provided value, and returns `true` if a value was removed. Otherwise it returns `false`.

```
public bool Remove(T item) 
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) 
    {
       if (_items[i].Equals(item)) 
       {
         RemoveAt(i); 
         return true; 
       }
    } 
    return false; 
}

public void RemoveAt(int index)
{
    if (index >= Count)
    {
        throw new Exception("Index out of Range");
    }

    var sourceIndex = index + 1;
    Array.Copy(_array, sourceIndex, _array, index, _array.Length - sourceIndex);

    Count--;
}
```

Comment: Your loop will return after the `item` is removed. There is no nested loops here

Comment: Simply profile some tests for different n to get a good idea of the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool Remove(T item) 
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) // say count = n. this loop will run n times.
    {
       if (_items[i].Equals(item)) // say if operation takes 10 units of time
       {
         RemoveAt(i);  
         return true;  // say this operation takes 2 units of time
       }
    } 
    return false; // say this operation takes 2 units of time
}

public void RemoveAt(int index) {
    if (index >= Count) // say this operation takes 10 units of time
    {
        throw new Exception("Index out of Range"); // say this operation takes 4 units of time
    }

    var sourceIndex = index + 1; // say this operation takes 2 units of time
    Array.Copy(_array, sourceIndex, _array, index, _array.Length - sourceIndex); // say this operation takes 10 units of time

    Count--; // say this operation takes 5 units of time
}
```

This means `RemoveAt` takes 10 + 4 + 2 + 10 + 5 units of time = 31 units of time
And `Remove` takes n * (10 + 31 + 2) units of time  = n * 43 units of time.

Any operation that takes a constant amount of time is called an `O(1)` operation. So, `Remove` takes `n * O(1)` units of time, which is of the order of `O(n)`

Comment: oh nice. Can you accept my answer if it was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm needs at most *O*(*n*) steps:

- Copying the array in `RemoveAt` requires at most *O*(*n*) steps.
- Traversing the array in `Remove` requires at most *O*(*n*) steps, too.
- Since `RemoveAt` is called at most once from `Remove` the total running time is: *O*(*n*) + 1 * *O*(*n*) = *O*(*2n*) = *O*(*n*).